# Delete cookies UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cookies, uiwebview

How to delete cookies in UIWebView? This code:

```
NSArray* cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
 [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

deletes cookies but when I restart my application, there are same cookies in NSHTTPCookieStorage. Sometimes this code works, but i want to make it work everytime.How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
        for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
            [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
```

Comment: You said that code working sometimes. Can you say more about it?

Comment: I mean it works random, i can't controll this:) In same questions people write about some lag in ios 4.0++. Cookies deleting while your app is launching, if app has been restarted, cookies return)

Comment: Cookie saved in NSUserDefaults, so to clean them you can remove all your NSUserDefaults data, like this: `NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

NSArray *allCookies = [cookies cookies];

for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in allCookies) {
    if([[cookie domain] rangeOfString:@"facebook.com"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

deleting a single cookie does not always work for some odd reason. To truly get a cookie deleted you will need to store the not specific cookie and then reload them and then iterate through all cookies and delete them such as this

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
   if (cookies != nil && cookies.count > 0) {
       for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
           [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
       }
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

in the end...  Works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

The similar for previous one but simplier:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

NSArray *allCookies = [cookies cookies];

for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in allCookies) {
    if([[cookie domain] contains:@"facebook.com"]) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

The "best answer" is bad because it allows to delete cookies for the specified concrete URLs. So for example you delete cookie for "login.facebook.com" but you may miss "www.login.facebook.com"